# Performance - Search a table with 20 million records using Spring JPA Data

Tags: sql, spring-boot, performance, spring-data-jpa, query-optimization

I have a requirement where I need to search the Users in a table with millions of records using the first name with wildcard and return the top 100 records by sorting them ascending.

My query is executing for more than 2 minutes and my repository would look like below,

`List<User> findTop100ByFirstNameStartsWithOrderByFirstName(String firstName);`

Is there any other way in Spring that I can achieve this without compromising the performance.

Comment: Put an index on firstName

Answer (score 1):

Start by [explaining the SQL query](https://www.sitepoint.com/explain-sql-explain-queries/) created by `findTop100ByFirstNameStartsWithOrderByFirstName` repository method. If the SQL query results in a full table scan you can consider creating an index on the `FirstName` column to speed up the query as it should offer [high cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)).

There are different index types and each of them provides a different trade-off. Indexes are not free, their creation and maintenance will consume database server resources. If your query is run once a month it might not be worth it.

If above makes no sense to you read [Use The Index, Luke!](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) or any other documentation that explains database indexes.